# How to audit changes to the AWS account

Tags: amazon-web-services, alert, audit

I wanted to know if there was a way to track alerts or audit anything that happens with the AWS account like who changed what and why. I did find this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/audit-logs.html where they use a comand line for enabling audit logs on an existing domain: `aws opensearch update-domain-config --domain-name my-domain --log-publishing-options "AUDIT_LOGS={CloudWatchLogsLogGroupArn=arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789012:log-group:my-log-group,Enabled=true}"` but this is in regard to Amazon OpenSearch Service which I believe is only free for 12 months if you haven't used already. AWS Audit Manager. I am aware there are services that can do this but require a fee and I wanted to know if there were any free options

Comment: AWS Config and CloudTrail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the AWS documentation:

> With **AWS CloudTrail**, you can monitor your AWS deployments in the cloud by getting a history of AWS API calls for your account, including API calls made by using the AWS Management Console, the AWS SDKs, the command line tools, and higher-level AWS services. You can also identify which users and accounts called AWS APIs for services that support CloudTrail, the source IP address from which the calls were made, and when the calls occurred. You can integrate CloudTrail into applications using the API, automate trail creation for your organization, check the status of your trails, and control how administrators turn CloudTrail logging on and off.
>
> **AWS Config** provides a detailed view of the resources associated with your AWS account, including how they are configured, how they are related to one another, and how the configurations and their relationships have changed over time.

Basically, **AWS CloudTrail** keeps a log of API calls (requests to AWS to do/change stuff), while **AWS Config** tracks how individual configurations have changed over time (for a limited range of resources, such as  Security Group rule being changed).